# Multiple mongo queries then return response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm trying to get the list of collections in my db and then return every document in those collections for backup purposes. As of now the payload still returns blank. How do you wait for payload to be populated before sending? also where would my db.close() go?

Note: I know i'm getting the data properly because if I console.log(data) instead of pushing it it works fine.

````
app.post('/admin/saveMongoDB',async(req,res)=>{
  let payload=[]
  MongoClient.connect(url,{ useNewUrlParser: true}, function (err, db){
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("probes");
    dbo.listCollections().toArray().then(ctx=>{
      ctx.forEach(probe=>{
       dbo.collection(probe.name).find().toArray().then(data=>{
         payload.push(data)
        }).catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
      })
      res.send(payload)
    })
  })
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your `payload` would indeed be an empty array as `ctx.forEach` is executed after `res.send(payload)`

Since you're using `Promise` you could re-write your code to utilise `Promise.all`:

```
dbo.listCollections().toArray().then(ctx => {
  const colls = ctx.map(probe => dbo.collection(probe.name).find().toArray())
  const Promise.all(colls)
    .then(results => {
      // results is an array
      res.send(results)
      db.close();
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
})
```

One thing to note is `Promise.all`'s *fail-fast* feature. If any promise fails (one of your db query fails) then `then` will not be called at all. But since you're taking backup, am assuming this would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/admin/saveMongoDB', async (req, res) => {
  let payload = []
  let i = 0
  MongoClient.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("Accuprobes");
    dbo.listCollections().toArray().then(ctx => {
      ctx.forEach(probe => {
        dbo.collection(probe.name).find().toArray().then(data => {
          i++
          payload.push({
            [probe.name]: data
          })
          if (i == ctx.length) {
            res.send(payload)
            fs.writeFile('./backups/accuprobeHistoricalData' + (new Date).getTime() + '.txt', JSON.stringify(payload), function (err) {
              if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
              }
              console.log('MongoDB Succesfully Saved')
            })
          }
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I ended up solving my issue by creating an iterator and when that matched the amount of probes, I then sent my response.